# Error en flutter al listar datos

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

Estoy intentando listar, ya tengo mi metodo "Future" el cual traigo todos los datos y los convierto en un json. despues tengo el siguiente código.

```
  Future<String> getData()async{
    var url = 'http://201.182.250.76/pedido_flutter/Listar.php';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

> Se me presenta un error en dos lineas de codigo.

```
  body: FutureBuilder<String>(
    future: getData(),
    builder: (
        BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot,
        ) {
      if(snapshot.hasError)
        print(snapshot.error);
```

> La primera en la linea (itemCount: snapshot.data.length,;)

```
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
```

> El segundo error se presenta en la linea( List list = snapshot.data;)

```
            List list = snapshot.data;
            return ListTile(
              leading: GestureDetector(child: Icon(Icons.edit),
                onTap: (){
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddEditPage(list: list,index: index,),),);
                  debugPrint('Edit Clicked');
                },),
              title: Text(list[index]['lastname']),
              subtitle: Text(list[index]['phone']),
              trailing: GestureDetector(child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onTap: (){
                  setState(() {
                    var url = 'http://192.168.1.104/php-mysql-flutter-crud/delete.php';
                    http.post(Uri.parse(url),body: {
                      'id' : list[index]['id'],
                    });
                  });
                  debugPrint('delete Clicked');
                },),
            );
          }
      )
          : CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Cuáles son los errores?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el error _específico_ que estás teniendo. Ponlo también en el título de la pregunta.

Comment: Está bastante raro el código, la verdad. Una cosilla, si estás usando un ListView dentro del Future, supongo que estás recibiendo una lista, ¿no? Pero el tipo indicado en el Future es tipo `String`, lo cual es un único elemento. Además, no veo el return en el if del error, por lo que no queda claro si estás reaccionando a no tener datos, correctamente. ¿Podrías poner la parte del FutureBuilder completa?